# Terminology about elongating a monothong or a diphthong by duration and tone

Tags: phonology, phonetics, terminology, vowels

Which terminology is applicable when a monothong or diphthong is elongated in duration and with a slightly higher pitch?  Would it be vowel breaking or fracturing or something else?

Example 1 (monophthong CAR  /ˈkɑːr/) The word 'CAR' as uttered by Person B in the following scenario:
Person A: "I think I left it in the car"
Person B: "No, it's not in the CA-AR"
Sound clip available in SOUNDCLOUD:
https://soundcloud.com/pepe888-1/pronunciation-of-car-diphthongized

Example 2 (HOME / həʊm /)  The word 'HOME' as in the following scenario:
Boy has just got home, he walks through the front door and wants to let his mom know before he even sees her and he says, "Mom, I'm ho-ome"
pronunciation of 'HOME' is stretched and ends with a higher pitch, sound clip available in SOUNDCLOUD:
https://soundcloud.com/pepe888-1/vowel-breaking-example